# Automatically start supervisord installed in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, supervisord

All, 
I'm using supervisord under python3, which is under development. Installation is done via pip, and under a virtualenv, using this:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor.git
```

version from pip freeze: supervisord==4.0.0-dev.

This means one has to run supervisord after activating the virtualenv. I've found [this script](https://gist.github.com/howthebodyworks/176149) (with further details [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/96499/how-to-automatically-start-supervisord-on-linux-ubuntu)) which allows supervisord to start automatically, but not when it's installed via pip, in a virtualenv.

Is there a way to start supervisord as a service, automatically, under a virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have* to activate the virtualenv to run the `supervisord` and `supervisorctl` scripts.

Just use `DAEMON=/path/to/virtualenv/bin/supervisord` in the script to start the daemon.